# FloatingActionButton over last item of list

Tags: flutter, dart, floating-action-button

I have a scrollable list with a `FloatingActionButton`. I would like to make the list to finish before the `FloatingActionButton` because last item of list isn't visible anymore(`FloatingActionButton` it's over list item)

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    controller: _scrollController,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: <Widget>[
      _buildUpcomingExpansionTileEvents(myUpcomingEvents),
      _buildPastExpansionTileEvents(myPastEvents),
    ],
  ),
  floatingActionButton: UnicornDialer(
    parentButtonBackground: Colors.blue,
    orientation: UnicornOrientation.VERTICAL,
    parentButton: Icon(OMIcons.add),
    childButtons: childButtons,
  ),
);
```

How could I change my list to finish with one empty item? Or what's the best solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're having a problem with, can you maybe provide an image of what you have currently?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`FloatingActionButton` has size of `56` for non-mini and `40` for mini, so what you can do is use `padding` in `ListView` like:

```dart
ListView(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 56), // if you have non-mini FAB else use 40
  // ...
),
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve this I just add a sized box as the last element in the list. That way you still get the end of list highlight in the correct place when the user scrolls to the bottom of the list.

```dart
ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  controller: _scrollController,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  children: <Widget>[
    _buildUpcomingExpansionTileEvents(myUpcomingEvents),
    _buildPastExpansionTileEvents(myPastEvents),
    SizedBox(
      height: 100, // or whatever height works for your design
    ),
  ],
),
```